# Set pointer to a value plus a separate value

Tags: c++, pointers

Is it possible to set a pointer to a value but with a slight offset.

Something like:

```
m_NewPosition = &m_Position + Vector3(0,0,10);
```

So the value NewPosition is the actual position plus 10 infront.

Using c++.

Comment: Why do you want to add a vector to the address of `m_Position`?

Comment: Really weird question, what would adding a 3 dimensional offset to a pointer to linear memory do? If you're talking strictly vector math, then there's no trouble with your code snippet save for the &.

Comment: This is like adding 2 kg and 3 mm to get 5 A. I.e. not meaningful.

Comment: `m_Position + Vector3(0, 0, 10)`. You don't need (or want) pointers here.

Comment: Am I doing this wrong? I use a pointer because I want m_NewPosition to change as m_Position changes.

Comment: Make `operator+` produce a new vector, don't try to mutate anything here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can perform arithematic on a pointer, but unless the newly pointed address points to something valid dereferencing it would result in UB.

Comment: Thank you for the swift reply. The Vector3 is something I made. When I try the above I'm told there's no + operator which takes type Vector3. Do I have to create a new operator that deals with pointers?

Comment: @Dave: If `Vector3` is your own data type, naturally the standard library `+` operator is not aware of it and does not provide a overload for your custom class type.

Comment: I'm afraid you misunderstood the question (which was not very clear, to say the least): I think the OP wants `m_NewPosition` to be kept in sync with `m_Position`, so that every change to `m_Position` is reflected on `m_NewPosition`.

Answer (score 3):

You can only use offsets with pointers if the pointer points into an array.

So if you have `char arr[10];` and you fill it up with something, then you could do `char *p = arr + calc_offset();`, providing you don't go out of bounds of the array.

from C++ standard:

> If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the
>   same array object, or one past  the last element of the array object,
>   the evaluation shall not produce an overﬂow; otherwise, the behavior
>   is  undeﬁned.

Comment: This is certainly not the only case. Consider a struct.

Comment: @user606723: pointer arithmetic is only defined within arrays.

Comment: @user606723: Say hello to undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Xeo "Hello UB!", sorry couldn't resist :P

Comment: Hrm, I guess I can't imagine it not working... Is it also undefined behavior to cast similar structs like beej's guide does?

Comment: I'm afraid you misunderstood the question (which was not very clear, to say the least): I think the OP wants `m_NewPosition` to be kept in sync with `m_Position`, so that every change to `m_Position` is reflected on `m_NewPosition` (see [@Benjamin's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9605061/20984) and [mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9606323/20984)).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're actually looking for is a function, whose result varies with the value of `m_Position`.  I take it, by the `m_` prefix, that these are both members.  If the `m_Position + Vector3(0,0,10)` is constant, it could just be a normal member function:

```
Vector3 m_NewPosition() const {
    return m_Position + Vector(0,0,10);
}
```

But if you want the ability to change the function, then you could use `std::function<Vector3(void)>`, and assign it like this:

```
m_NewPosition = [&m_Position]() { return m_Position + Vector3(0,0,10); };
```

Here's a simple example, but with integers instead of Vectors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct Foo
{
    Foo()
        :X(0)
    {
        NewX = [&X]() { return X + 10; };
    }

    int X;
    std::function<int(void)> NewX;
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    for (f.X=0; f.X<10; ++f.X)
    {
        std::cout << f.NewX() << '\n';
    }
}
```

And a demo online so you can view the output of that: http://ideone.com/XTwE7

---

Another option is to make sure that both m_Position and m_NewPosition are private, and never modify them directly, but only through accessor functions, e.g.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void IncrementPosition(const Vector3 & rhs)
    {
        m_Position += rhs;
        m_NewPosition = m_Position + Vector3(0,0,10);
    }
private:
    Vector3 m_Position, m_NewPosition;
};
```

Comment: I think you are the only one who correctly understood the question (which was not that clear, to be fair).

Answer (score 1):

It seems odd that you would want to take the address of `m_Position` and add a vector to it. Perhaps it would help us more if we knew where your pointers are. We don't know the types of either `m_NewPosition` or `m_Position` so it's hard to help. However, it seems very unlikely that you will need pointers here at all.

I will assume that those two variables are of type `Position`, which is a class that looks something like:

```
class Position {
 public:
  Position(int x, int y, int z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) { }
 private:
  int x;
  int y;
  int z;
}
```

If this is the case, and you want to apply addition to this position with a `Vector3`  as the second operand, then you need to overload `operator+` on this class. To do that, do something like this:

```
class Position {
 public:
  Position(int x, int y, int z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) { }
  Position operator+(const Vector3& vector) {
    return Position(x + vector.x, y + vector.y, z + vector.z);
  }
 private:
  int x;
  int y;
  int z;
}
```

As you can see, the `operator+` method allows you to add a vector to this position. Now you would just do:

```
m_NewPosition = m_Position + Vector3(0,0,10);
```

In this example, however, `m_Position` won't change. It will stay as the same position it always was. The call to `operator+` will just return a new `Position` with the updated components. If you want to update `m_Position`, then you probably want to overload `operator+=` instead.

Comment: I don't want to add to the address. Vector3 is a class which holds 3 floats. m_Position and m_NewPosition are both of type Vector3. I was trying to add multiple collision components to a character. Each component would be positioned at the players position plus a distance. It's my lack of knowledge that's confused the question. By making new position a pointer to position the components move with the player.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want `m_NewPosition` to be at all times equal to `m_Position` plus some offset in space, even when it is modified (something along the lines of [reactive programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming)). This is not achievable the way you tried to do it, you should probably find some good reference about pointers. However, you have some solutions at your disposal.

The first one is to use a function/method, [like @Benjamin Lindley proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9605061/20984): since `NewPosition` is a computed value, it makes sense to compute it in a function:

```
class Character
{
  public:
    Vector3 getPosition() const
    {
        return m_Position;
    }

    Vector3 getNewPosition() const
    {
        return getPosition() + Vector3(0, 0, 10);
    }

  private:
    Vector3 m_Position;
};
```

This is the entire point of encapsulation, meaning hiding the internals of your object: the "visible" properties of your object should be accessible only through member functions (methods), allowing you to change the way they are stored or to compute them on-the-fly, like `m_NewPosition` in your example.

Another solution, more complex (and probably not appropriate in your case), is to write a new class that represents a relative position:

```
class RelativePosition
{
  public:
    RelativePosition(Vector3 const & origin, Vector3 const & offset)
      : m_Origin(origin), m_Offset(offset)
    {}

    Vector3 getAbsolutePosition() const
    {
        return m_Origin + m_Offset;
    }

  private:
    Vector3 const & m_Origin;
    Vector3 m_offset;
};
```

Note how `RelativePosition` stores a reference to its origin, and not a copy; thanks to that, if the origin is modified (i.e. moved), the relative position will reflect this change.

Now, you can use an instance of this class to represent `m_newPosition`, which is indeed a relative position (relative to `m_Position`, with an offset of `Vector3(0, 0, 10)). However, as I said previously, I think this solution is probably overkill for your case; you should probably stick to the previous approach.